# find solutions of : $x^2-2x+2=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If am I asked to find the solutions of : $x^2-2x+2=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$,what do I have to do?
Do I have to find the numbers that are in $\mathbb{Z}_6$,which are $\{ [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]\}$ and check each $[a],0 \leq a \leq 5$ if it is a solution replacing it at the given equation or is there also an other way to solve the exercise?

Comment: For a modulus as small as $6$, I'd say that just checking each possible value is by far the easiest.

Comment: And if I would have a bigger number,what could I do??

Comment: As that is $(x-1)^2+1 \equiv 0 $, you need to check if $-1$ is a residue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^2-2x+2=(x-1)^2+1$ and so solving $x^2-2x+2=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to finding a square root of $-1$ mod $m$. Quadratic reciprocity gives you the complete answer.

Comment: It's a long time ago, but when I learned about quadratic reciprocity, it seemed to be all about whether a solution _exists_. Is there a way to use it to actually _find_ the solution?

Answer (score 1):

One other approach is to check for a solution mod 2 and mod 3 and combine them using the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) (if they exist), for example mod 2 the solution is very easy to obtain, but mod 3...